# Entity framework 4 : Why are related entites loaded even though there is no Include statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'm using entity framework 4.
I have 2 objects : a Process object, and a ProcessDescription object. There is a one to one association between the Process and the ProcessDescription (a Process always have a ProcessDescription)

I'm doing the following:

```
using (EFEntities ef = new EFEntities(ConnectionString.EFConnString))
        {                                
            var source = ef.Process;
            List<BusinessLayer.Process> processList = source.ToList();
        }
```

After the ToList statement, if I inspect the processList in the debugger, I can see that the ProcessDescription object is available for each Process, and I'm wondering why. I thought I had to write the .Include("ProcessDescription") to include them. Is it automagically loaded because it's a one-to-one association?

Update: The EnableLazyLoading is indeed set to true. My question is: If that property is set to true, I thought that the related entities would be loaded, but only when needed. To check if it's loaded, we can use the IsLoaded flag on the related entities. However, in my case, there is no IsLoaded property on my ProcessDescription object. Does it mean that when I do the 'ToList()' there is a inner join that is performed automatically, again because it's a one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn lazy loading off and you will see null values in the debugger.

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.contextoptions.aspx

(assuming Database First with ObjectContext)

Answer (score 0):

In relations between entities, entity framework automatically loads all associated entities. you can disable it by setting `ef.ContextOptions.LazyLoading = false` inside using statement.

Comment: It's not just one to one relations, it's all related entities if the LazyLoading flag is true on your model.  If you never want lazy loading disabled by default, you can change it in the model itself.  If you want one off scenarios, you can do it as @Jalalx mentioned.